# using texture as variable

Tags: textures, directx11, hlsl

I was trying to use a texture as a variable in my shader (DX11 VS/PS 5.0). Can't get it.
I have recently find this piece of code [here](https://sugulee.wordpress.com/2021/01/19/screen-space-reflections-implementation-and-optimization-part-2-hi-z-tracing-method/) where a texture is passed as a function parameter.
Is that compatible with DX11 VS/PS 5.0 and can I transform this to have in a ps shader a texture as variable that I can modify on demand in a loop (for or while).

```
kernel void kernel_createHiZ(texture2d<float, access::read> depth [[ texture(0) ]],
                     texture2d<float, access::write> outDepth [[ texture(1) ]],
                            uint2 tid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
```

Comment: Would you be able to stack the textures you want to switch between into a texture array, and then vary the index into that array?

Comment: Yes surely but I noticed a slow down when using texture arrays. I have finally decided to have 4 textures instead of texture[4] or texturearray with 4 slices. So I'm using a test to select the texture to work with. This was fine with one call in my ps shader with 4 layers to have a minimum depth and the corresponding color. But I was limited in my HiZ search to the main depth buffer with limited results and wants now to make HiZ on the 4 layers.  So being able to have a global variable with the selected textures could be nice.